# Git でコミットした内容が消えてしまいました

Tags: git

Git でコミットした内容が消えてしまいました。GitHubの ブラウザのコンソールから新しいブランチ（branch-3）を作りました。

ローカルでbranch-3を修正しました。

```
% git branch
* (HEAD detached from origin/branch-3)
branch-1
branch-2
```

git pushしようとしたところ、以下のようなエラーが表示されました。

```
% git push origin HEAD

error: The destination you provided is not a full refname (i.e.,
starting with "refs/"). We tried to guess what you meant by:

- Looking for a ref that matches 'HEAD' on the remote side.
- Checking if the <src> being pushed ('HEAD')
is a ref in "refs/{heads,tags}/". If so we add a corresponding
refs/{heads,tags}/ prefix on the remote side.

Neither worked, so we gave up. You must fully qualify the ref.
hint: The <src> part of the refspec is a commit object.
hint: Did you mean to create a new branch by pushing to
hint: 'HEAD:refs/heads/HEAD'?
```

よくわからず

```
$ git checkout branch-3
```

したらommitする内容になってしまいました。
もう復元不可能でしょうか？

```
$ git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at origin/branch-3)
branch-1
branch-2
branch-3
master
remotes/origin/branch-1
remotes/origin/branch-2
```

```
$ git reflog
3676487 (HEAD -> branch-3, origin/master, origin/branch-3) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 367648702311ad0e5f0451b582fd895bb68b9d07 to branch-3
3676487 (HEAD -> issue-7, origin/master, origin/branch-3) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from issue-7 to origin/branch-3
3676487 (HEAD -> issue-7, origin/master, origin/issue-3) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from 34345434440ec0daba27f694ce92ffb93a410f to branch-3
4049480 HEAD@{3}: commit:VERY IMPORTANT MODIFY.
```

Comment: 念のため、`git status` の実行結果も質問に追記してみてください。

Comment: `git branch -a` の出力はそれで全てですか？ `remotes/origin/branch-3` は存在しませんか？

Answer (score 1):

(おそらく記載されている情報が正確でないのでは、という気がしていますが…)

`4049480` が復元したい内容でしょうか？(`git show 4049480` や `git log -p 4049480` で確認できます)

であれば次のコマンドで `branch-3` に変更内容を `push` できます:

```sh
git push origin 4049480:branch-3
```

もし `push` したい内容が `4049480`ではない場合でも、 `git reflog` 結果から `commit` した内容は取り出すことができると思います(のでそのハッシュ値で `push` すれば良いです)。